# MVC 5 Ajax Issue

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, unobtrusive-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm learning MVC5 and I'm trying to implement a simple page to add and display students. The question takes lot of space but is extremely basic.

[image: My Form]

So here is the model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the action methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Students.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView();
        }

        return PartialView(student);
    }
```

Here is the Parent view:
**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCAjax.Models.Student>
<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="row" id="myformbase">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Action("Create")
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the child view: **Create.cshtml**

```
@model MVCAjax.Models.Student
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Student", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myform" }))
{
    <div id="myform">
        <h2>Create</h2>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Student</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now I've have few issues:

1. When I type student name and age and click create, the text boxes still show values instead of getting cleared. The data gets saved in the db.
2. What if I want to update the List on the left part as soon as new student is added.

I've a little experience of MVC4 and there if I used to pass (in AjaxOptions) the Id of div that contained both the child divs (in my case "myformbase") then it used to update it. But not sure why this doesn't work in MVC5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just add `ModelState.Clear();` after you have saved record in to database;
2. Try to change UpdateTargetId to the base container ID:

   `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Student", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myformbase" })){...}`

Comment: Thanks. It solved my first problem. Any Idea about the second one?

Answer (score 1):

> When I type student name and age and click create, the text boxes
>   still show values instead of getting cleared. The data gets saved in
>   the db.

A Right way to solve this problem is to do a [POST-REDIRECT-GET (PRG)](http://sampathloku.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-use-prg-pattern-with-aspnet-mvc-4.html). Alternatively you can create a empty model and bind it with view (I mean `Student s = new Student(); return PartialView(s);`).

> What if I want to update the List on the left part as soon as new
>   student is added.

PRG will solve your problem in this case also. So redirect to Index Action, once Create is completed. Alternatively you can use AJAX GET to the Index Action and load the html in the view.